# How to find the average case complexity of Stable marriage problem(Gale Shapley)?

Tags: computational-complexity

[Stable marriage problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem)

So I know that the worst case complexity will be of the order O(n^2)
and the best case is of the order O(n).
But how can I calculate the average case complexity

Answer (score -1):

Average case efficiency: $$\mathcal{O} \left( n \log n \right)$$

Comment: Could you elaborte further?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).